# Is there a language where collections can be used as objects without altering the behavior?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, language-features, list

Is there a language where **collections** can be used as **objects** without altering the behavior?

As an example, first, imagine those functions work:

```
function capitalize(str) 
    //suppose this *modifies* a string object capitalizing it
function greet(person):
    print("Hello, " + person)

capitalize("pedro")
>> "Pedro"

greet("Pedro")
>> "Hello, Pedro"
```

Now, suppose we define a standard collection with some strings:

```
people = ["ed","steve","john"]
```

Then, this will call toUpper() on each object on that list

```
people.toUpper() 
>> ["Ed","Steve","John"]
```

And this will call greet once for EACH people on the list, instead of sending the list as argument

```
greet(people)
>> "Hello, Ed"
>> "Hello, Steve"
>> "Hello, John"
```

Comment: The only language feature you need is LISP's map. You would do something like `(map toUpper arr)` in Clojure. Forgive me if I got the order wrong. Everything else should be built as a library. Just adding auto map to a language is not a good idea - it does not give you flexibility. What about upper-casing every second item? A powerful library such as LINQ or python's itertools or basic lisp primitives can let you do that. Anyhow, I have not heard of such language, thank God (I second DeadMG's opinion).

Comment: I think your reasoning is an really great, but I don't think it would not give you flexibility. Upper-casing every second object would be spelled as each_2(people).toUpper() or the like.

Comment: I am unclear how you could make this work in a way that wouldn't be a confusing mess.  What happens with a list of lists of strings?  What happens with a dictionary of lists of strings?  How on Earth do you handle all those cases implicitly?  Languages like Python allow far more complexity and variety while avoiding the sort of confusion this would cause.  Far better to allow simple features that allow people to very explicitly deal with this.  Note that every your special case "Upper-casing every second object" needs special syntax.

Comment: I guess the confusion comes from the fact you are not used to it but it's pretty simple if you think about it. Every variable is not a name anymore, but a collection. The old variable is colection with one element. A list of a list is just a list of a list, a = [[1,2],[3,4]]. Calling a.foo() would translate to [1,2].foo(), [3,4].foo(), which would translate to 1.foo(), 2.foo(), 3.foo(), 4.foo(). It is the simplest way as I see things. It almost kills the necessity of using for-loops in most case, making the code surprisingly beautiful because it express itself.

Comment: birds = [myBird1, myBird2, myBird3]; birds.fly();

This is superior to the so-common and repetitive "for (bird in birds): bird.fly()" (in Python, that is already the shortest way to write this).

What I mean is that doing something with a group of elements is more common than calling array methods (such as .sort, .push) and thus array.method should cast the method for each element, and the today standard array.sort should be spelled as sort(array) instead. I don't see why it would cause any problem in any way.

Comment: Oh, and for the function application part, *kill(birds)* is, too, more readable than *for bird in birds: kill(bird)*, so it should be the standard behavior. If you want to send a array to a function (this is not so common) you could anotate as foo([birds]), which I don't see as problematic, at all, and would actually even add further to readability, even for unrelated cases.

Comment: I think you are confusing terseness with readability.

Comment: In `C#` you can declare `void Foo(params int[] numbers) { ... }`. This syntactic sugar helps a bit and it does not turn C# into Perl or VB.Net. Now, the fact that in VB.Net and some other languages you can call a method with no parameters without spelling parenthesis is really annoying - it does something you do not necessarily expect. I feel the same way about implicit conversion operators and some PowerShell quirks. I want to be able to understand what code does quickly. This 'feature' introdues a potential for bugs http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: @Job: I find it quite interesting that you mention LINQ, since the language LINQ came from ([Cω](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/comega/)) has *exactly* the feature the OP is looking for.

Comment: So, it should not be part of the language. It is just rarely used. There are lots of other standard features that a language might need first. Another point - it forces something down peoples throats that they might not necessarily like. Even Python's white space mandate causes quite a bit of controversy. Suppose C# supported the syntax that you speak of. Also suppose I had an extension method `public static void Print(this IList<string> strs)` then the "auto-map" feature would conflict with MY EXTENSION METHOD - a feature I find much more valuable. If I can use a `map`, then why have 2 ways?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, good find! I do not have the best answer. I wish Eric Lippert commented on this. He could give us a bulleted list, 360 view of why this would not be a good idea with C#. Now, I do not know Haskell, F#, have not studied category theory or taken a class that compares languages, but I have taken a few math classes and have listened to half of SICP lectures plus some Clojure videos. My intuition and experience tells me that it is good to keep things explicit, simple, elegant, general. There is a good reason why this feature has not gained much popularity. LINQ does not have it :)

Comment: Doesn't jquery work a bit like this?

Comment: Job, how is calling a function/method for a group of elements rarely used? It is possibly the most used thing at all. Note: not sure why you are coming with languages such as C# or C, which were not designed with this on mind and thus obviously won't mix with the idea nor really have or need to.

Comment: have you ever met the list monad?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there are such languages. Many of them.

In fact, this feature is pretty much the *definition* of an *array language* or *vector language*. Examples of array and vector languages include, but are not limited to, the APL family of languages with its successors, derivatives and cousins (E.g. APL, J, K) and pretty much all mathematical and statistical languages such as Mathematica, MATLAB, Octave, R, and S.

Fortran 90 and Ada also have this feature, as does Fortress.

Interestingly, many modern CPUs also support vector programming, e.g. the x86 architecture with the MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3 (Intel) and 3DNow! (AMD) instruction sets, the POWER and PowerPC architectures with the VMX and AltiVec instruction sets, Sparc, MIPS, even ARM.

The [Cω](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/comega/) language by Microsoft Research has the concept of *streams* (roughly similar to `IEnumerable`). Streams pretty much work exactly as you describe. Here's an example from the [Cω documentation](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/comega/doc/comega_whatis.htm) (emphasis mine):

> A key programming feature of Cω is generalized member access: the familiar 'dot' operator is now much more powerful. Thus **if the receiver is a stream, then the member access is mapped over the elements**, e.g. **`zones.ToString()` implicitly maps the method call over the elements of the stream `zones` and returns a value of type `string*`**. This feature significantly reduces the burden on the programmer.

A very interesting property of this kind of programming is that it not only allows you to semantically *think* of "applying an operation to all elements at once", it also allows the language implementor to *implement* it by *literally* applying an operation to all elements *at once*, IOW *in parallel*.

Comment: This is the kind of answer that encorages me using Stack, when everyone just attacked the idea or said with certainty it does not exist (why?). I have much to explore now. Thank you.

Comment: @Dokkat: Thanks for the kind words. I try my best.

Comment: Sorry for not choosing your answer before, guess I forgot.

Comment: I would also add Numpy/Scipy Python libraries to the list: http://numpy.scipy.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can get semantics very similar to what you're asking for in nearly all languages using the composite pattern.

Given you have some type similar to this:

```
// pseudocode
class CustomString
{
    CustomString Composite;
    string Value;
}
```

... and a `Greet` method like this:

```
// pseudocode
public string Greet(CustomString cs)
{
    string ret;
    if (cs!= null)
        ret += "Hello " + cs.Value + newline;

    if (cs.Composite != null)
        ret += Greet(cs.Composite);
}
```

... you can make calls like this:

```
writeln(Greet(new CustomString("snorfys")))
>> Hello snorfys

cs = new CustomString("snorfys") { Composite = new CustomString("Dokkat") }
writeln(Greet(cs))
>> Hello snorfys
>> Hello Dokkat
```

If you do a lot of work with trees, programming in this way feels common quickly (that is to say that each tree node is, and can be treated as, a subtree).

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you've done there? I should read about that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In C# for example there are extensions (add the functionality to the collection - underneath it would still be a loop, but nothing visible) and Linq - example:

```
public static IEnumerble<string> Capitalize(this IEnumerable<string> collection)
{
   var List<string> rtn = new List<string>(collection.Count());
   foreach (var item in collection) 
   {
      var ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; 
      var textInfo = ci.TextInfo; 

      rtn.Add(textInfo.ToTitleCase(item)); 
   }
   return rtn;
}
```

[Note: I hand keyed this - so maybe some typos errors]

alternatively, ...

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{  
   source.ThrowIfNull("source");     
   action.ThrowIfNull("action");    
   foreach (T element in source)    
   {         
        action(element);     
   } 
}
```

with a function for capitalize

```
public static string Capitalize(this string str)
{
    var ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; 
    var textInfo = ci.TextInfo; 

    return textInfo.ToTitleCase(str); 
 }
```

and then

```
myColl.ForEach(x => x.Capitalize());
```

The difference is the second allows you to pass any function along and for any collection type.

```
myCollection.Where(employee => emplyee.Age > 50).ForEach(employee => employee.Fire());
```

works too (in a heartless sort of way :D )